# May I use UIViews to manage a large number of animated sprites? Or is it better to stick with CALayers?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, uiview, calayer

that' my first question here on Stack Overflow. I'm making a columns inspired game for iPhone, that's my first serious project on iphone. I chose to use CALayers to implement it, it looked like a good choice, layers are simple and don't have the unnecessay (for this purpose) gagdets of UIviews.

Sadly I just recently discovered CALayers do not yet support filters and blending options, at least not officially. I've read many questions regarding performance differences between UIViews and CALayers, but seems I can't find a clear answer.

In my game it may happen to have up to 140 non-opaque sprites (70 static sprites, each one with an animated overlay) moving on screen in certain conditions, with collisions and some physics. With CALayers performance is very good, a large number of moving sprites seems to have low impact on performance and I managed to have 30 fps in the worst case, with the bottleneck being physics.

The only thing I feel the lack of are blending effects.

At this point OpenGL is hardly an option to me. For what I've understood I'd have blending effects with UIViews, my concern is about performance, I've read UIViews should not be used with a large number of sprites, especially if updating is frequent as is in my case.

Could it be worth a try? Any suggestion to add effects on layers?

Comment: If you're not into GL, how about using a nice game engine like Cocos or Unity?

Comment: Where did you hear/read that you can have filters and blending effects with views? Last time I checked, layers had more drawing capabilities than views. I'm not sure what kind of effects you are after. Your layers can have opacity so you can perform some basic blending there. Please add some examples of the kinds of effects you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Vji: it's not a matter of optimization...

Comment: @CodaFi: cocos and unity are great piece of software. btw, for this project i've built my small 2D engine based on layers to increase my knowledge, especially about layers and to check the limits of layers, blending modes being one of them. I'm not going with OpenGl both because i'm not an expert and because i'd have to rewrite the whole game, i'd prefer not :) Anyway unity for ios is not free and not very cheap, it's $400!

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: well, yes, i was confusing. I've read something about CIFilters, never used them, some filters are available on iOS but of course these are for images, so that's not an option, it would be terribly slow. I'm using opacity but that's not much, i'd like to have more blending options: subtract or multiply colours, etc. but also obtain other effects like blur and spherical distortion (like CIBumpDistortion). Is there any fast solution out there? Guess i just have to wait for filters to be implemented for layers.

Comment: Core Graphics has more advanced blending options but would probably have a performance impact. Other than that you basically have to use OpenGL for high performance "filters" aka. shaders